# Manage csproj file in CI/CD process

Tags: azure, tfs, webforms, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have an asp.net web forms application. To implement Continuous integration/deployment process:

**TFS**

- Dev branch
- Master branch

**Azure: App service**

- Dev Slot
- Staging Slot
- Prod

The lifecycle is :

1. The developer add some features and commit it to Dev branch ==> the commit will be automatically deployed to Dev slot
2. The requestor or the client see, test and validate modifications
3. If it is Ok ==> the developer merge his changeset to master branch
4. when the changeset were merged with success, it will be ==>

   - deployed to Staging slot
   - Test some important Url in staging slot
   - If it is OK ==> Swap Staging and Production slots

So at the end, we will have the versions of the application:

1. Version N+1 in the dev slot
2. Version N-1 in the staging slot
3. Version N in the production

This process works fine. Because of the csproj file, in some it didn't

**Example :**

- A Developer  add a subsite A and B
- site B is validated by the client but site A did not
- when the site B's changeset were merged to the master branch, the csproj file will contains A and B pages references
- So we will have a compilation error in master, because site A's pages are mentionned in the csproj but it doesn't exist in this master branch!

So I need to know how can I fix this issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git for source control?

Comment: @DanielMann I use TFVC

Answer (score 3):

You have a continuously integrated dev branch. When it comes to deploying, you find yourself asking the question, "How do I deliver a subset of what's presently in the branch?" At this point, you're trying to essentially un-merge. You don't ever want to "unmerge".

Instead, consider adopting a feature toggle pattern. This is a developer-centric activity, not a branching/merging activity. Your developers wrap any new feature behind a toggle that can be conditionally enabled or disabled. If Site B is approved for deployment and Site A isn't, that's fine -- deploy with Site A's feature toggle disabled. It's still in the code, but there's no way for your end-users to access it.

Another possibility is to adopt a microservice architecture where there are fewer hard dependencies. Instead, your application is comprised of many, smaller, independently versioned and deployed services. This will probably end up involving feature toggles too, of course.

The above two thoughts are coming from a place of modern application design. To go back to an older way of thinking: If you need to "unmerge", it means you're merging too early. You may need to maintain multiple development branches and QA features independently, only merging them together once the changes have been approved. This, of course, requires a longer QA cycle because you'll have to QA both features a second time, after they are merged.